# Instalando gnuhealth y tryton

Tags: postgresql

¡Hola!
Soy nueva en tryton. Estoy instalando gnuhealth.
Ya instalé gnuhealth y postgresql.
Cuando intento iniciar sesión en tryton dice:
trytond.security falló para 'gnuhealth' de '127.0.0.1' en la base de datos 'gnuhealth'.
Sin embargo, el usuario y la contraseña son correctos.
Ya cambié "md5" por "trust" en pg_dba.conf y puse la uri correcta en trytond.conf.
También configuré el perfil en la ventana de inicio de sesión.
Pero nada funciona.
Gracias por cualquier ayuda.